# 100% to 100% Flex application preloader positioning

Tags: apache-flex, preloader

I've got a problem trying to apply a loading animation to my Flex application - a whole browser window occupant.
I'm subclassing DownloadProgressBar class as described on Adobe's [article](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=app_container_4.html) about this. `stageHeight` and `stageWidth`, reported by base class are incorrect. It says 500x375 pixels in constructor and 0x0 elsewhere. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you solved this problem? I have the same problem with my flex app.
Stage returns 500x375. 
My workaround is not pretty. This function is called on FlexEvent.INIT_PROGRESS. So when my application is available i use its props.

```
private function onFlexInitProgress( event:FlexEvent ):void {
    if (Application.application != null){
        var appWidth:Number = Application.application.width;
        var appHeight:Number = Application.application.height;
        x = (appWidth * 0.5) - (preloaderSWF.width * 0.5);
        y = (appHeight * 0.5);
        preloaderSWF.visible = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help but I think its possible to reference the size of the Flex application by using Application.width, Application.height.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=app_container_2.html

The issues below seem to be related to your issue:

http://www.nabble.com/Stupid-Question---Flex-width-and-height-td21423345.html

http://www.nabble.com/Flex-stage-size-td20167125.html

http://dreamweaverforum.info/flex/125327-referencing-stage-flex.html

Hope they help.

Answer (score 0):

A width/height measurement of 0x0 is often indicative of the component in question not having been fully laid out at the time of the reading (including child components). Checking measurements in the constructor is surely too early. You'll want to check the measurements after you've set the stage to fullscreen and everything you're displaying has been laid out, probably at the applications creationComplete event, perhaps even later. The following link should be a good resource:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/07/creating-full-screen-flex-applications/

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is add an event listener to the stage for its resize event and adjust the size of your preloader accordingly. Otherwise if someone resizes your Flex app while the preloader is displayed it will not resize.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onStageResize);

public function onStageResize(e : Event) : void {
    this.width = stage.stageWidth;
    this.height = stage.stageHeight;
}
```

Or alternatively you can center your preloader on the stage using code like so:

```
preloader.x = this.stage.stageWidth/2 - preloader.width/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem in an actionscript project in flash builder, using 100% to 100% width and height. I observed that stage.stageWidth and stage.stageHeight was 500x375 until after the preloader had loaded the main class, then it would change to the full screen size. Because of this, the positioning of items in the preloader was incorrect. I discovered that it was this line in my main class that was getting the stage size to update:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

Here is how I implemented it in my preloader:

```
public function Preloader()
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
    }

    private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align=StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        ...
    }
```